# Allow members of one Google group to post (but not be members of) another group

Tags: google-groups

At my school we have a group for each class in the school, where the owner is the class teacher, and the students are members. We also have a group for all of the teachers. I want any teacher to be able to post to any of the class groups, but not to be a member of all class groups. Is there any way to do this other than opening the permissions to allow anyone in the school to post to the class groups?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 7 times. It doesn't include enough details, and there have been several changes in Google Groups and the Google accounts for schools. If you are still looking for an answer, please update the question and include more details like the type of accounts that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

(My answer is not tested with GAFE.)

To achieve the desired functionality, subscribe each teacher to each class group, but with "delivery setting" set to "no email."

This next idea is just fantasy -- I wonder if you could subscribe the name of the teachers group, and also set it to "no email"?